# How do I expire rails4 cache fragment by hash including a certain key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I built cache keys with this logic

```
    key = {
      action: 'a',
      company: 5
    }
```

how do I use expire all keys where company is 5?

```
    expire_fragment(keys_including_company_5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't provide any built-in mechanism for expiring cache based on an attribute. At least not anymore, as in the past there was a feature called cache sweeper that was partially designed to expire cache fragment explicitly.

The best way would be to use rather than the company ID, a field which is composed by the id and an attribute you can change (e.g. a timestamp or a counter).

In fact, ActiveRecord model `cache_key` is generated appending the id and the `updated_at` field.

In this way, expiring the cache for an item would be a simply matter of increasing the counter or updating the timestamp.